# Alternate Perl environment for testing

Tags: testing, perl, installation

My [testing environment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) includes some older platforms. I'm trying to test OpenSSL on an older Debian 6 platform, and the OpenSSL test scripts are having trouble with Perl 5.10. So I am trying to fix a *"Test::More version 0.96 required..."* when running OpenSSL's test suite.

I downloaded Perl 5.22.1, built it from sources, and installed it in `/opt/perl` with `./configure -des -Dprefix=/opt/perl`:

```
$ ls /opt/perl/
bin  lib

$ ls -Al /opt/perl/bin/ | grep perl
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 1879707 Mar 30 12:01 perl
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 1879707 Mar 30 12:01 perl5.22.1
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root   45365 Mar 30 12:01 perlbug
...

$ ls /opt/perl/lib
5.22.1  site_perl
```

I created a script to forward calls into the new Perl:

```
$ which perl
/usr/local/bin/perl

$ cat /usr/local/bin/perl
#!/usr/bin/env bash

LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/perl/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"; PERL5LIB="/opt/perl/lib/5.22.1:$PERL5LIB"; \
/opt/perl/bin/perl5.22.1 "$@"
```

However, when I run the OpenSSL test script I continue to encounter *"Test::More version 0.96 required..."* (both with and without `PERL5LIB`):

```
$ make test
( cd test; \
      SRCTOP=../. \
      BLDTOP=../. \
      EXE_EXT= \
      OPENSSL_ENGINES=.././engines \
        /usr/bin/perl .././test/run_tests.pl  )
../test/recipes/01-test_abort.t ........... Test::More version 0.96 required--this is only version 0.92 
...
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong with the new Perl on this testing machine.

What's wrong with the Perl installation?

---

`Test::More` is available:

```
$ find /opt/perl -name '*More*'
/opt/perl/lib/5.22.1/Test/More.pm
```

And it seems to be a version that meets requirements:

```
$ cat /opt/perl/lib/5.22.1/Test/More.pm | grep VERSION
our $VERSION = '1.001014';
$VERSION = eval $VERSION;    ## no critic (BuiltinFunctions::ProhibitStringyEval)
```

---

Related, I'm not experienced with Perl, so I have lots of gaps. I thought it had to do with `PERL5LIB` since `Test::More` seems to be related to it. Perl's INSTALL has this to say:

> When using the newer perl, you can add these paths again in the
>   PERL5LIB environment variable or with perl's -I runtime option.

I don't quite understand why the new PM files would not be included with the new Perl by default. And I don't understand why adding them via `PERL5LIB` does not resolve the issue. So I guess it means `PERL5LIB` is not part of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debugging these is never fun...

Your problem is that when you `make test` it eventually does `/usr/bin/perl .././test/run_tests.pl` which is going to pull in the old Perl and not the new Perl you created.

You need to either figure out where it gets that /usr/bin/perl from, or to put your new Perl there instead.  A natural guess is that you began installing with your old Perl, installed a new one, went back to your old one, and it has the original configuration.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you're right. I cleared the hard coding in most places with `/usr/bin/env perl` (about 120 of them), but that damn makefile has it hard coded, too. I needed a `make test PERL=/usr/local/bin/perl`.